# Show average value only if combination is present x number of times

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table (airfare_data) containing the columns city1 (Origin), city2 (Destination), quarter, fare. There are many rows of flights recorded in the data, often between the same cities. I am trying to find the average fare per quarter, excluding routes that didn't take place in all 4 quarters.

I have the following command:

```
select distinct city1, city2, quarter, round(avg(fare),0)AvgF  
FROM airfare_data  
GROUP BY 1,2,3  
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

It gives the following results

city1 city2   quarter AvgF
Albany, NY  Denver, CO  1   224
Albany, NY  Denver, CO  2   256
Albany, NY  Denver, CO  3   256
Albany, NY  Denver, CO  4   255
Albany, NY  Fort Myers, FL  1   200

As the combination of Albany, NY, and Fort Myers, FL only occurs in Q1 I would like to exclude it from my table, but I am not sure how. The original table includes multiple rows of the combination Albany, NY and Fort Myers, FL, so just want to show where any combination is present in all 4 Qs.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` window function:

```
SELECT city1, city2, quarter, AvgF
FROM (
  SELECT city1, city2, quarter, 
         ROUND(AVG(fare), 0) AvgF,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY city1, city2) counter
  FROM airfare_data  
  GROUP BY city1, city2, quarter
) t
WHERE t.counter = 4
ORDER BY city1, city2, quarter
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT city1, city2, quarter, round(avg(fare),0) as AvgF  
FROM airfare_data  
GROUP BY 1,2,3 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
ORDER BY 1,2,3;
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` is only very, very, very rarely used with `GROUP BY`.

EDIT:

For your revised question:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT quarter) > 1
```

or:

HAVING MIN(quarter) <> MAX(quarter)

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. Apologies for not being clearer in my question. There are multiple rows with the combination Albany, NY and Fort Myers, FL, however, they all occur in Q1. Is there a way to put the count on the distinct combination?

Comment: @sqlrory . . . Use `count(distinct quarter) > 1`.  No subquery is needed.